# Jquery Modal Pop Up

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am  using  asp.net image button when we click the image button  Modal popup will display. now My problem is when i click the button popup is coming but it post back to the server after that popup window is closed  can u give the solution for this

My Code is

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgemail" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/images.jpg" /> 

$("#imgemail").click(function() {

 $("#dialog").dialog("open"); 

});
```

Comment: why r u using <asp:ImageButton> button?

Comment: for fast solution please paste ur code...

Comment: asp.net image button any other button  can we use?

Comment: u r opening pop on click of <asp:ImageButton> then u dont need to postback so u can use simply image also...

Comment: Ok, Can You Send the Sample COde My  code is

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="imgemail" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/images.jpg"  />     $("#imgemail").click(function() {
               $("#dialog").dialog("open");


           });

Comment: just use <asp:Image> instead of <asp:ImageButton>

Comment: ur welcome... and ask question like I edit so u can get fast answer

Comment: how to write a code modelpop  i want code for sending an email where ineed to write a code for this?

Comment: you can use http://fancybox.net/ it is good pop plugin.

Comment: thats fine  back round code i want where  i need to write a code ?

Comment: in model pop window  i am displaying field to, from, body,   for sending mail   in tht  when i click a  button in model pop up the  mailshould be send  tht mail code where i need to  write?

Comment: create a page and write the code of sending mail and open it in fancybox's iframe option

Comment: i didn't get properly can u send some samples regarding this....

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific need, there is no point in doing an ASP.NET Image Button, you could do something like this.

```
<a id="lnkEmail">
    <img src="/images/images.jpg" alt="Your text" />
</a>

$("#lnkEmail").click(function() {

 $("#dialog").dialog("open"); 

});
```

Now, you would want to set additional attributes on the image etc, but you get the idea.